# Custom reset root ViewController segue doesn't show proper navigation bar titles and buttons

Tags: ios, swift

I have got this custom segue which resets root view controller with a custom transition.

```
class ResetRootViewControllerSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let src = source
        let dst = destination
        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: .curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            },
                       completion: { _ in
                        src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: {
                            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = dst
                        })
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Root ViewController is a TabbarViewController which incapsulates navigation bars in each tab.

The problem.

When I execute this code only in the first navigation bar is shown. The other navigation bar titles are empty.

This code without animation doesn't work too

```
 class ResetRootViewControllerSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
        override func perform() {
            let src = source
            let dst = destination
            src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
            dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

                            src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: {
                                UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = dst
                            })

        }
    }
```

But when I use this class without animation all works fine.

```
class ResetRootViewControllerSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let src = source
        let dst = destination
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = dst
    }
}
```

this simple animation works too

```
class ResetRootViewControllerSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {
    override func perform() {
        let src = source
        let dst = destination
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = dst
        UIView.transition(with: (UIApplication.shared.delegate!).window!!,
                          duration: 4.0,
                          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: { UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = dst },
                          completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Any ideas how can I implement my custom transition animation?